# How is 4H‐1,4‐oxazocine aromatic?

Tags: organic-chemistry, bond, aromatic-compounds, aromaticity

I’ve found 4*H*‐1,4‐oxazocine in my chemistry book and I’m perplex as it states as aromatic:

[image: 4H‐1,4‐oxazocine]

I can count six electrons on p orbitals which could satisfy Hückel’s $n = 1,$ but the oxygen is sp<sup>3</sup>-hybridized. Even if we’d consider one lone pair as one sp<sup>2</sup>-bonding, the second lone pair would add 2 electrons to the p system, counting a total of 8 electrons, which doesn’t satisfy Hückel’s rule.

Comment: So what about the nitrogen lone pair?

Comment: @Waylander so basically I could count n=10 considering O as $sp^2$ with a lone pair on the pi system?

Comment: Didn't we do the same in furan? Didn't we do the same in pyrrole? Well, now put the two together.

Comment: @IvanNeretin Thanks! I actually had this preconception I’ve read somewhere that n=number of aromatic rings, thus in my reasoning this compound couldn’t have more than 6 e^- in its pi system.

Comment: @pseuronimo n is not the number of aromatic rings, nor could it be since the 4n+2 rule is really accurate only for a single ring.  Rather it's an optimal value that depends on ring size.  Typically n=0 for a three-atom ring, 1 for 4-7 atoms, 2 for 8-9 atoms.  Aromaticity is usually insignificant for larger rings than that.

Comment: @OscarLanzi I'd say n=0 for 3-4, 1 for 5-8, 2 for 8-11 or 12.

Comment: I am more conservative; aromatic dication rings and rings with ten or more atoms are less common and may not always be energetically favored; for example $\ce{C_{11}H_{11}^+}$ is not an aromatic ring.

Answer (score 8):

According to [Huckel's rule](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Organic_Chemistry/Map%3A_Organic_Chemistry_(Wade)/17%3A_Aromatic_Compounds/17.05%3A_Aromatic_Antiaromatic_and_Nonaromatic_Compounds) four criteria for aromaticity

The molecule needs to be (1) planar, (2) cyclic, (3) fully conjugated, and has (4) 4n+2 electrons.

Your molecule does not seem to be planar (b/c of N and O atoms) but assuming that it has a nearly planar conformation it satisfies all other criteria.
You only need to count one of oxygen's lone pair and the only nitrogen lone pair:

$10=4*2+2$

So it could be aromatic (if it is nearly planar)